# How to call func in parent component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a btn in parent component and func in child component

```
<parent>
  <child/>
  <button onClick={myFunc}>call func</button>
</parent>
<child>
  const myFunc = () => {
    ...
  }
  return{
  }
</child>
```

Comment: You pass the function as a prop to the child. So, something like this: `<parent><child handleFunction={myFunc} /> </parent>` and in the child: `const child = ({...props}) => { return <button onClick={props.handleFunction}>Call Parent Function</button>};`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call child method from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent)